# NodeJS use both express and socket

Tags: node.js, sockets

i'm newbie in nodejs and i want to post and get data to nodejs server and have realtime inside application and server. in this code my code is not correct. i'm using both of `express` and `socket` and i cannot handle that in application. is both of that correct?

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var express  = require('express');
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io  = require('socket.io');  

var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Configuration
app.use(connect.logger('dev'));
app.use(connect.json());  
app.use(connect.urlencoded());

// Routes

require('./routes/routes.js')(app);
var server = io.listen(4732);

server.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {  
    console.log('hello');
    socket.on('user', function(data) {
        if (data.type == "client") {
            mk_socket = socket;
        }
    });

});
console.log('The App runs on port ' + port);
```

My android client:

```
SocketIO socketio = null;
try {
    socketio = new SocketIO(SERVER_ADDRESS);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
socketio.connect(new IOCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
        System.out.println("Server said: " + "SALAM");
        //Toast.makeText(G.currentActivity, "SALAM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
        System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
        System.out.println("an Error occured");
        //Toast.makeText(G.currentActivity, "an Error occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        socketIOException.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnect() {
        System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnect() {
        System.out.println("Connection established");
        //Toast.makeText(G.currentActivity, "Connection established", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
        System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
        //Toast.makeText(G.currentActivity, "Server triggered event", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

socketio.emit("user", new JSONObject());
```

for example i dont get `hello` when i use:

```
socketio.emit("user", new JSONObject());
```

, thanks

Comment: Ohh Man. Your `process.env.PORT` is 8080 and you are listen server over 4732

Comment: @underscore oh!! thanks, i'm update post, please review that